# How to detect loss of accessibility focus with on-screen navigation buttons?

Tags: android, focus, accessibility, kindle-fire

I'm looking at the Support4Demos from the Android SDK and I'm not sure if this is working as intended.  Specifically, I'm referring to accessibility focus when using the Widget > Explore by Touch Helper demo.  If I tap on one of the blue regions to give it accessibility focus then tap on the on-screen home button focus will switch to the home button.  But if I tap on the same blue region as before nothing happens (but if I tap on the other blue region focus transfers from the home button).  I'm testing this on a Kindle with on-screen navigation buttons.

Am I correct in assuming that focus should transfer back to the blue region?  If so, what is the proper way to handle this?  Presumably there would be a way to know that the user tapped on something outside of the app and in response to this I could clear state in the ExploreByTouchHelper but I'm not sure how I would go about that.

Comment: Touching outside of the window doesn't clear accessibility focus, so focus never left the blue region. With the latest version of TalkBack, however, this shouldn't be an issue and tapping in an already focused area should speak it again.

Comment: @alanv Thank you for the answer.  Having TalkBack repeat the description is ultimately what I'm looking for (focus isn't important for application logic in this case so I can live with that).  Any recommendations on work-arounds or more information on when this was fixed in TalkBack?  Thanks again!

Comment: What version of TalkBack do you have installed? If it's the latest version from Play Store, it should work.

Comment: This is on a Kindle running FireOS so I'm not 100% sure that it's using TalkBack.  I see something called ScreenReader at version 3.4.22 but I may need to find someone at Amazon to explain the difference.

Comment: Oh, they probably branched TalkBack at some older version. Ugh. For what it's worth, you might want to try contacting them and asking if it'll ever get updated.